# Problem With Database Design For MVC - 1 Table Per Model

Tags: model-view-controller, database-design

My biggest hurdle with getting started with an MVC framework has to do with with the 1 model to 1 DB table concept. To me it's overly simplistic and unrealistic for anything beyond a simple app. Yet, MVC is in use everywhere, including this awesome StackOverflow site. As is typical, all of the code examples and tutorials i come across are very simple and the 1 to 1 relationship works fine in those cases. But, what i'm looking for is a solid real world example of an MVC model that address table joins. In the case of stackoverflow, i would imagine a DB design with tables like Questions, Tags, Users, etc. In my DB design I may have a Question_Tag link table to to look up all tags associated with a given question. How does MVC deal with this?

Comment: Yea, you are getting confused.  ORMs and a MVC pattern can be used together, but really, are mutually exclusive

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't believe that there is anything about [the MVC design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) that states that there should be one database table per domain class. In fact, there is nothing about the MVC design pattern that even says that your model should be or has to be persisted in a relational database.

This is just the strategy that some popular frameworks (Ruby on Rails - maybe ASP.NET MVC too?) have taken on, for what appears to be convenience sake. But it is not a requirement of MVC.  Spring MVC (for the Java world) has no inherent concept of how to map the model components to a database, in fact it's beauty is that it doesn't care - you just need to supply the model data to use, and where you get it from the MVC framework doesn't care about.

So in other words, you don't need to assume that the MVC pattern means that you have to use one database table per model component. Heck you don't even need to use a database, your model could come just as well from a flat file or web services (and what's great about MVC is that if you design your app properly, you could swap different data layer implementations in and out of your application and the View or Controller *won't even know*).

Comment: It's not even a requirement in Rails, more like a default starting point.

Comment: Matt you are correct. After another week of digging deeper I get this now. There's a lot more flexibility allowed in the model component than i had thought. It seems you can write your DAL however you like and even have seperate BLL and DAL layers or neither.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are confusing MVC with ORM. ORMS bind you one to one with Database Tables and Objects.

What you need to do is send your Model objects from your MVC to a DAL layer that can populate them for you from SQL queries and return you the objects. Similarly you can send the populated objects with changes back to the DAL layer to be persisted.

This is a much cleaner and flexible design that you can use with the MVC pattern and you do not have to couple your objects to database tables, while using the join capabilities of SQL.

Comment: "ORMS bind you one to one with Database Tables and Objects."  

This statement is not true at all.  Every .NET ORM solution has the capability to map complex joined queries to single objects.  ORMs solve the impedance mismatch problem with is exactly the opposite of a one to one relationship.

Comment: *which is exactly the opposite, sorry, typo

Answer (score 1):

OK Ahmad that makes sense. But in all of the MVC examples I've seen, the model is something of a combined BLL/DAL. What you're talking about is keeping the Model as a pure BLL and creating a separate DAL. I thought one of the main features of using an existing mvc framework was to speed up development. If I'm going to have to create a DAL on top of MVC I may as well stick with my existing non-MVC development process of a creating pages with separate business logic and data access layers.

Comment: You could use a code generator to generate your DAL the way I mentioned if you think it is too much work. But keeping your DAL separate from your Model is key to a flexible design and keeping data access logic out of your MVC.